# Opentelemetry Java agent Not Send Span after config

Tags: java, spring-boot, open-telemetry

Like tittle said after i set Vm Option

```
-Dotel.traces.exporter=jaeger
-Dotel.metrics.exporter=none
-Dotel.exporter.jaeger.endpoint=http://localhost:14250
-Dotel.instrumentation.common.default-enabled=false
-Dotel.instrumentation.opentelemetry-api.enabled=true
-Dotel.instrumentation.opentelemetry-instrumentation-annotations.enabled=true
```

the agent stop send any span to jaeger anymore

acording to this doc https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/agent-config/
The section Enable manual instrumentation only
it's should only Export span with @Withspan annotation
But it's seems like export nothing

Any Help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My guess is that you are using the old annotation:

> `io.opentelemetry.extension.annotations.WithSpan`

and `-Dotel.instrumentation.opentelemetry-instrumentation-annotations.enabled=true` applies to the new annotation:

> `io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.annotations.WithSpan`.